# How to nest jinja variable in url_for

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am trying to do something like this:

```
<li style="font-family:Roboto;"><a href="{{ url_for('flight', id={{ flight.id }}) }}">{{ flight.origin }} to {{ flight.destination }}</a></li>
```

with Jinja and Python Flask. When I run it, I get this:

```
 <li style="font-family:Roboto;"><a href="{{ url_for('flight', id={{ flight.id }}) }}">{{ flight.origin }} to {{ flight.destination }}</a></li>
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'
```

It works when I change `{{ flight.id }}` to a regular number. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why not: <li style="font-family:Roboto;"><a href="{{ url_for('flight', id=flight.id) }}">{{ flight.origin }} to {{ flight.destination }}</a></li>

Comment: @voscausa you're right. Can you post this as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not:

```
<li style="font-family:Roboto;">
    <a href="{{ url_for('flight', id=flight.id) }}">  <!-- changed -->
        {{ flight.origin }} to {{ flight.destination }}
    </a>
</li>
```